# How to use graphics.h in windows tdm gcc compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, bgi

I am using 64 bit windows 7 pc and i recently installed tdm gcc compiler. Initially i was working on turboc so my program is created in graphics.h. But now i want to use tdm-gcc compiler and it is showing an error as follows

```
sstream: no such file or directory.
#include<sstream>       //provides std ostringstream
```

Comment: Add a sample of your code

Comment: Please post `gcc` command line

Comment: `sstream` is C++ . Use `g++` instead of `gcc` for using it.

Comment: but i coded it in c language

Comment: It is showing an error because you are using the C compiler but requested a C++ header file. `sstream` is only available to C++ not C.

Comment: If you want to simulate Turbo Visions graphics.h in modern compilers you could take a look at http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/libgraph/

Comment: @Brandin I have already done that and it still shows the same error. Please help me....

Comment: @samson How experienced are you with C? If you are learning you may need to practice a bit more. The libgraph thing is a possible way to port your old Turbo Graphics code. Libgraph uses SDL to display the graphics but it pretends like its graphics.h. BTW never used it myself so in the end you have to download it and give it a try and then come back with specific questions and specific error messages if you need help.